# How to retrieve previous/next entry in a Django DetailView view

Tags: python, django, detailview

I'm using a class based view DetailView to handle the layout of a blog post.

In the template, I need to implement a button to show previous/next posts ordered by timestamp. For this reason, I need to override the context by customising the `get_context_data(self)` method.
In the context I thus need to add the instances of prev/next entries by `insertion_date` relative to current post.

**views.py**

```
class EntryDetailView(DetailView):
    model = Entry

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EntryDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['base_url'] = self.request.build_absolute_uri("/").rstrip("/")

        return context
```

**models.py**

```
from .managers import EntryManager

class Entry(models.Model):
    """ Blog Entry
    """
    insertion_date = models.DateTimeField('inserimento', auto_now_add=True)
```

Thank you for any help you could provide.

Comment: [`get_next_by_FOO`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_next_by_FOO)

Comment: thank you @DanielRoseman, but how can I get the current entry instance in get_context_data(self, **kwargs)?

Comment: I don't see why you need to, since you can call that method from the template. But it's in `self.object`, see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#django.views.generic.detail.DetailView).

Comment: it works! good stuff to know, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Just use the Django's  get_previous_by_created and get_next_by_created qweryset

***Note the  created should be a field in your Post model***

example

```
<ul class="post-nav group">
                   {% if post.get_previous_by_created %}
                    <li class="prev">
                        <strong>Previous Article</strong>
                        <a rel="prev" href="{{post.get_previous_by_created.get_absolute_url }}">
                            {{ post.get_previous_by_created}}</a>
                    </li>
                   {% endif %}
               {% if post.get_next_by_created%}
                     <li class="next">
                        <strong>Next Article</strong>
                         <a rel="next" href="{{ post.get_next_by_created.get_absolute_url}}">
                             {{ post.get_next_by_created.slug}}
                         </a>
                     </li>
               {% endif %}
```

***Note post should be context variable in your post detail view***